# GzipHandler.setCompressionLevel() method not available in latest release

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, jetty

**Jetty version : 11.0.15**

**Java version : 17**

I am trying to update my Spring boot project to 3.1.0. I need GZip compression for reduce response data size. For that I use spring-boot-starter-jetty instead of tomcat server. It download jettry version 11.0.15.

GZip config file

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.jetty.JettyServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;

@Configuration
public class GZipConfig {

    @Bean
    public JettyServletWebServerFactory jettyServletWebServerFactory() throws IOException {
        JettyServletWebServerFactory factory = new JettyServletWebServerFactory();
        factory.addServerCustomizers((Server server) -> {
            GzipHandler gzipHandler = new GzipHandler();
            gzipHandler.setInflateBufferSize(1);
            gzipHandler.setHandler(server.getHandler());
            gzipHandler.setIncludedMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT");
            gzipHandler.setCompressionLevel(Deflater.BEST_SPEED);

            HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection(gzipHandler);
            server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
        });

        QueuedThreadPool threadPool = new QueuedThreadPool();
        threadPool.setMinThreads(10);
        threadPool.setMaxThreads(200);
        threadPool.setIdleTimeout(600000);
        factory.setThreadPool(threadPool);

        return factory;
    }

}
```

Versions before jetty 9.x has GzipHandler.setCompressionLevel() method to set compression level. But it is not available since jetty 10.x.

How I set compression level in latest jettry server versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GzipHandler` now uses an `InflaterPool` and `DeflaterPool`, so you will need to configure this pool instead of using a `gzipHandler.setCompressionLevel()` method.

Instead use something like this

```java
gzipHandler.setDeflaterPool(new DeflaterPool(CompressionPool.DEFAULT_CAPACITY, Deflater.BEST_SPEED, true));
```

You could also just create the `DeflaterPool` and add it as a bean on the server and it will be shared by any components which also need the pool, and it will be automatically detected by the `GzipHandler` without using `setDeflaterPool()` explictly.